# Tick marks disappear on secondary x-axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot that has two x-axes.  I have 11 tick marks for the top x-axis defined as follows:

```
plt.xticks([0 , 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 , 50 , 60 , 70 , 80 , 90 , 100])
```

I then have my second x-axis tick marks defined as follows:

```
par2.xaxis.set_ticklabels([0, r'$1.5\times 10^{8}' , r'$1.5\times10^{9}' , r'$7.3\times10^{9}' , 
r'$2.4\times10^{10}', r'$6.1\times10^{10}' , r'$1.2\times10^{11}', r'$2.0\times10^{11}', 
r'$2.9\times10^{11}', r'$3.6\times10^{11}', 0])
```

If I have the first x-axis tick marks defined first in the code then I get all of the tick marks on the top x-axis but not on the bottom as follows:
[image: Plot with all the tick marks on first x-axis]

If I move the plt.xtics in the code to below where the tick marks are defined for the second x-axis then I get all of the tick marks on the secondary axis and not on the first as follows:

[image: Plot with all the tick marks on the second axis and not on the first]

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to make all of my tick marks show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why that happens, but I think it has to do with the defaults for a new axis. What I would do is to copy the ticks number from the first axis (that I'll call **par1**):

```
TicksNum = len(par1.xaxis.get_major_ticks())
par2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins = TicksNum) )
par2.xaxis.set_ticklabels([0, r'$1.5\times 10^{8}', r'$1.5\times10^{9}', r'$7.3\times10^{9}', r'$2.4\times10^{10}', r'$6.1\times10^{10}', r'$1.2\times10^{11}', r'$2.0\times10^{11}', r'$2.9\times10^{11}', r'$3.6\times10^{11}', 0])
```

Comment: Thanks!  So this didn't exactly solve the issue but you got me on the right track to get it fixed.  I was using another example to where someone had written some functions to change the default behavior.  The x-axis looked very similar to how I wanted it so I never thought to change the functions.  Turned out I only needed to one function to modify the default behavior, the second function was just removed and all is well.